# Cocoa ARC: Remove window from memory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nswindow

I have a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSWindow *window;
```

And in my implementation, I have two methods, start and stop.

The start function creates a new window like so (partial code) :

```
_window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                           styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                             backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                               defer:NO];
```

The stop function closes the window like so:

```
[_window orderOut:self];
[_window close];
//_window = nil;
```

However, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I execute the start function for the second time (start, then stop, then start again).

This happens on the NSWindow alloc statement.

What do I need to do to make sure that a new window is created correctly?

**EDIT: After some more testing, it appears the error has nothing to do with the alloc init call. If I add the following line before that:**

```
 NSLog(@"%@", _window);
```

On first call to start, this will result in output "null", then after the call to stop() and the new call to start, I will get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the NSLog line.

Even just setting _window = nil; in the stop method (after calling [_window close];) causes a bad access error.

Comment: Without a backtrace, no one can help you.  Certainly not without more context.

Answer (score 0):

What's you need to add:

```
_window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                           styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                             backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                               defer:NO];
[_window setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
```

The reason you got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is
[the window is set to be released when closed, a release message is sent to the object after the current event is completed. For an NSWindow object, the default is to be released on closing.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419662-close?language=objc)