# ARC and window/view lifetime management

Tags: clang

So I'm a newbie to Objective-C, but experienced with C++ and I'm having a hard
time getting this application port to work.

It's a really simple tray menu app that's using a couple of foundation framework classes and is built directly from a terminal using a make like build script.  So it doesn't have an xcode project.

Aside from the menu, it has a single window that is used for OAuth style login purposes.  The window has a WebView attached.

The Objectice-C part of the app is not that big but has a lot of C++ interaction.

So in my AppDelegate.h I have the following.  I'm not sure whether loginWindow should be strong or not.

```
@property (strong) NSWindow            * loginWindow;
@property (strong) IBOutlet WebView    * loginView;
@property (strong) NSString            * state;
```

And the code that brings this up is here:

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Login Clicked");

    //if (!self.loginWindow){
        NSLog(@"Create loginWindow");
        NSUInteger windowStyle = (NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask);
        NSRect windowRect = NSMakeRect(100, 100, 400, 570);   
        self.loginWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowRect styleMask:windowStyle backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
        [self.loginWindow setTitle:@"ORBX Launcher - Login"];
    //}

    //if (!self.loginView){
        NSLog(@"Create loginView");
        self.loginView = [[WebView alloc] init];
        [self.loginView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
        [self.loginView setPolicyDelegate:self];
        [self.loginWindow setContentView:self.loginView];
    //}

    self.state = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:mString::Format("%.6f%08x", GetAccurateTime(), getpid()).str()];
    NSString *complete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", LoginURL, self.state];
    [[self.loginView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:complete]]];

    [self.loginWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp]; // Show window
}
```

Because login can be selected more than once from the menu, I didn't want to recreate the whole window again.  Which is why I had the !self.loginWindow stuff there.

So during the login process I capture a redirect to "localhost" which is used to signal completion and during that I call [self.loginWindow close].

It's fine until this point.  But if I logout and then call login again, it does a segfault 11.

So I thought perhaps it's something to do with the window needing to be recreated.  So I thought I'd release it.  Apparently ARC will do it for me if I assign the window to nil.  So I attempt that after close.

```
_loginWindow = nil
```

And it now segfaults as soon as the login completes. i.e. on destroying the window.  Maybe the view needs to be destroyed first?

```
_loginView = nil
```

And also a segfault.

I guess you could say the behaviour I'm seeing is identical to that described in this question with ARC enabled.  Unfortunately, there is no answer to it.

[Cocoa ARC: Remove window from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983664/cocoa-arc-remove-window-from-memory)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered hiding the window instead of closing it? Then when you need it later you just show it again instead of recreating it.

Comment: Yes I have, but that all get's thwarted when the red close window button is clicked.  I'd ideally like that behaviour left as it's standard, otherwise if there is a problem with the OAuth website, there is still a way to hide the window.  Unless you can make close work like hide instead.

Comment: You can set a window delegate and have that delegate implement `windowShouldClose:`. The delegate method can hide the window and return NO to prevent the close method from being called.

Comment: Just found that in the documentation.  I set the property releaseWhenClosed to NO and this achieved the same thing.  It's no longer crashing.  I'm not really sure if this is the best way to go about it but it seems to at least work now.